# iphone - Mail app - text kind of control

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to create a view which will be similar to iPhone's mail application.
In mail app, in the compose mode, after entering To, CC and Subject, I started entering text. As number of lines increases, the view will scroll up (still keeping the keyboard) and user will always be pointed to last line of the text.

How can we achieve such view. How can it be done.

Comment: this library might be helpful https://github.com/sunilsharma08/CustomTextView

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use the `UITextViewDelegate` and implement 
`(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView`

Then in  this implementation call `[textView bounds]` and obtain the height... Then shift your view accordingly.

Seems like there should be a better way though... Hope it gives you a start a least

Comment: Mail app just don't have text view I think, because it has different options to enter mail id, cc, subject etc.Also mail app still accepts images. How can we handle it?